# Как подгрузить изображение по клику?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть маленькое изображение, при клике на которое в определенный DIV должно подгружаться большое изображение. Во время подгрузки появляется GIF, которая показывает, что происходит загрузка. После загрузки GIF скрывается и появляется картинка. Как можно реализовать такую подгрузку?

Comment: Реализовать можно, написав соответствующий JS-код. Или раздобыв какую-нибудь библиотеку, делающую это за вас. С чем именно у вас возникла проблема, и что вы уже пробовали (ваш код) сделать?

Comment: Пробовал искать. Написал бы код, если бы знал, в какую сторону копать. Пока вообще никаких мыслей.

Comment: Добавляете обработчика события `click` для маленького изображения, в котором показываете GIF, добавляете обработчик `.onload` для большого обработчика и устанавливаете `.src` большого изображения. В обработчике `.onload` скрываете GIF и показываете большое изображение.

Comment: Пока не знаю :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1(простой):**

```
$(".click_img").on("click", function(){
    var obj = $(this).parrent();
    obj.html('<img src="loader.gif">');
    obj.html('<img src="image.png">');//Ваше изображение    
});

<div class="div">
    <img class="click_img" src="now_image.gif">
</div>
```

**Вариант 2( с ajax подгрузкой):**

```
$(".click_img").on("click", function(){
    var obj = $(this).parrent();
    obj.html('<img src="loader.gif">');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "name=test", //если нужно
        success: function(data){
        obj.html(data);
    }
 });

});

<div class="div">
    <img class="click_img" src="now_image.gif">
</div>
```

в файле `some.php` вы выводите Ваше изображение(я):

```
echo '<img src="image.png">';//Ваше изображение
```

Comment: а где здесь загрузка картинки? Вижу только php-файл.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов в some.php получаете картинку и далее грузите ее в `div`.

Comment: А в php как получить?

Comment: Изображение в папке на сервере, адрес расположения известен заранее.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов если адрес заранее известен, то Вам не нужен(скорее всего) запрос ajax. переписали ответ.